# XML error: Not well-formed (invalid token) phpldapadmin

Tags: xml, phpldapadmin

I am trying to set up a LDAP server and manage it with phpldapadmin.

If i open any element in my tree or try to create a new element am getting this error.

- `XML error: Not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1 in file /var/hda/web-apps/phpldapadmin/html/phpldapadmin/templates/creation/._sendmailVirtualDomain.xml`

If I uncomment and set `$config->custom->appearance['custom_templates_only'] = true` in the config file, then i am able to see any tree element and create new elements, but it is only limited to the templates that are custom.

any way of fixing this? what is it that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is getting a bit old, but here's an answer. There are some junk files in the template directory that the software is trying to read in. Try removing the files and I'd bet it will work

```
rm -f /var/hda/web-apps/phpldapadmin/html/phpldapadmin/templates/creation/._*
rm -f /var/hda/web-apps/phpldapadmin/html/phpldapadmin/templates/modification/._*
```

I used to have these sorts of hidden files pop up all the time when editing files from a Windows share on my Mac. Not sure if you've got anything similar going on or not...